# Issue with a workstation and file server shares

Tags: windows-server-2008-r2, windows-xp

I have a weird issue with a Windows XP SP3 computer in an office, as I'm trying to map network shares from a Windows 2008 server.

The server name is "server" and it's IP address is 10.10.10.10.

The problem I'm having is that if I were to do a net view \\10.10.10.10 from the problem computer, it would show the proper shares. If I were to do a net view \\server, it would show only one share, which happens to be non-existent. I don't know where this problem computer is seeing that.

No other machines in this office have that issue. Net view results between the IP and the host name is consistent.

Any suggestions?

Comment: `nbtstat -rR`on the client

Comment: Is the client properly resolving "Server" to 10.10.10.10 when you ping it?

Comment: This sounds like a name resolution issue and it sounds like the name `server` is resolving to an ip address other than the one you expect. What are you using for name resolution?

Answer (score 0):

Ok so this is what happened, ultimately....

To answer the questions, yes this machine did resolve properly to the 10.10.10.10 address.

I did the nbtstat -R and ipconfig /flushdns options, still the same results.

Here's what had to be done. It's long and winded. 
First thing - remove the machine from the domain.
Second thing - remove that computer's account from the domain controller.
Third thing - rename the computer.
Fourth thing - return the computer to the domain with the new name. That helped restore the consistency of the shares of the server if it was to be addressed by either its hostname or its IP address. However that was only achieved if I were to log in as the domain administrator on the affected client machine. If I were to log in as the existing domain user (which was "staff,") it would still show an inconsistency of the shares between the host name and IP.

Fifth thing - delete the Staff profile from the documents and settings folder. Restart the computer and log in as Staff, and let the computer rebuild the new profile. After that was done, the file shares were finally consistent, for that particular user, between the host name and IP.

Painful.